# How to mark as read inbox conversation with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I get message conversations via Facebook graph API which look like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/' + tid + '/messages?fields=message
```

and i want to mark as read the message but i can't found how to in documents.

please can someone point me to some examples.